# Add a class to parent and ancestors if the item have active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say that if I have code that looks something like below, and like to add `show` class to parent and ancestors.

```
// The last `nav-item` have `active` classs
<div class="nested-group nested-item show">
  <div class="nested-item show">
    <div class="nested-item show">
      <div class="nested-item show">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

// The last `nav-item` doesn't have `active` class
<div class="nested-group nested-item">
  <div class="nested-item">
    <div class="nested-item">
      <div class="nested-item">
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @guradio I was not sure where to start with, and Satpal's answer helped. Thanks. I am not sure why the question was down voted :)

Comment: not my downvote but maybe because you show minimal to no effort at all to solve you problem

Comment: @guradio you are correct, I should have explained it better, I knew there are `.parent()` and `.closest()` selectors but never knew `parents()` was there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) method to target all the parent/ancestors with `nested-item` class.

```js
$('.active.nav-item').parents('.nested-item').addClass('show');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nested-group nested-item ">
  <div class="nested-item ">
    <div class="nested-item ">
      <div class="nested-item ">
        <a class="nav-item active" href="#">Lorem</a>
        <a class="nav-item" href="#">Ipsum</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that helped. I knew there are `.parent()` and `.closest()` selectors but never knew `parents()` selector is there :)